# Remove docker0 bridge

Tags: bridge, docker

I'm using docker via

```
# service docker start
```

This creates a [`docker0`](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) bridge. However using

```
# service docker stop
```

doesn't remove this bridge.

How do I get rid of it? I'm not sure if I missed something here.

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/642981/docker-containers-cant-resolve-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04-desktop-host

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Just delete it:

```
ip link del docker0
```

(The old way, specific to bridges: `brctl delbr docker0`)

Comment: That was step one, but the `NetworkManager` still had the bridge. So calling `nmcli connection delete docker0` resolved the issue completely.

Comment: Thanks for the note @tynn, definitely useful when developing from a system with a GUI.

Comment: Will this solution prevent Docker from starting correctly after doing `service docker start` or will docker create the bridge again?

Comment: This is not an old way, you still need brctl package to do any bridges process.

Comment: No you don't. iproute2 is perfectly capable of doing the same.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka the bridge is created again when you start docker

Comment: For the googlers: Check command `docker network ls` and `docker network rm <ID>`. The ID is the same as in the br- or bridge name!